# Not getting video from cv2.VideoCapture from Parrot AR Drone

Tags: python, opencv, ar.drone

I am not getting video from `cv2.VideoCapture` from Parrot AR Drone: `ret` is always `False`

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("tcp://192.168.1.1:5555")

ret, frame = cap.read()

print ret

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I am not used to Python, but If it was in Windows I will first check whether cap is getting frames from the given IP Address using:

if(!cap.IsOpened())
{
cerr <<"No video Frames were read, please check your IP and Port" <<endl;
return -1;
}

This will easily help me know whether I am fetching from the Drone or not.

//Secondly, we have to check for the case where we are able to fetch from the drone..

while(true)
{
cap >>frame;
char c = waitkey(10);
if( c== 27) break
}
```